# Str_replace with insert title to database in php

Tags: php

I am trying to insert `str_replace` with title to database it inserting, but when I inserted lot of special characters to database my title display like this:

> login---form-using-c--

I want to insert like this title:

> Login-form-using-c

Here is my code:

```
$title=str_replace(" ","-",$title);
```

Comment: _special characters_ or spaces?

Comment: Are you trying to collapse special characters into a single `-` character? Can you provide more examples of the transform you are trying to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to trim spaces from either side and then replace 1 or more spaces:

```
$title = preg_replace("/\s+/ ", "-", trim($title));
```

Comment: Can you one more help i want to add  .html name end of the title. How to add it

Comment: Just concatenate `.".html";`

Comment: I don't know exactly add it to line. can you show me please

Comment: `$title = preg_replace("/\s+/ ", "-", trim($title)).".html";`

Comment: Thank you very much brother for helping me